# CSS : One of the DIVs gets positioned higher when window is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css

Pls see my codepen here: http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/oLpGOB

It looks fine, until you resize the window and reduce the width of the browser window, and then the first card becomes positioned taller than the rest of the 3 cards! What causes this and how do I fix it?

Tks!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.header {
  background-color: #1b9ef2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20rem;
}

.header h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 15rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.CardContainer {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -6rem;
}

.Card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30rem;
  margin: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
  padding: 0rem;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

.Card h2 {
  color: #1b9ef2;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding:2.5rem;
}

.cardimgcontainer
{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

.Card img
{
  width:80%;
  height:40%;
  max-height:180px;
  text-align:center;
}

.Card .Price
{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  padding:2.5rem;
  line-height:1.5rem;
  color:rgb(70,70,70);
}

.Card .Price .bold
{
  font-weight:800;
  font-size:1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Choose your subscription plan</h1>
</div>

<div class="CardContainer">
  <div class="Card">
    <h2>2 Days Trial</h2>
    <div class="cardimgcontainer">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/0d/e6/b3/0de6b34699563781365b286c45359692.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="Price"><span class="bold">$9.99</span><br />1 account</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Card">
    <h2>Personal</h2>
    <div class="cardimgcontainer">
      <img src="http://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/090/876/original/rolling-hills-landscape-vector.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="Price"><span class="bold">$29.99</span><br />5 accounts</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Card">
    <h2>Advanced</h2>
    <div class="cardimgcontainer">
      <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/968424/screenshots/2287311/2015_10_12_flatlandscape_800x600_v01_1x.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="Price"><span class="bold">$39.99</span><br />10 accounts</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Card">
    <h2>Business</h2>
    <div class="cardimgcontainer">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/18/fe/3f/18fe3f54a4ae949f7993442a9d8a3447.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="Price"><span class="bold">$49.99</span><br />50 accounts</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: adding     `vertical-align: top;` for `.card` fix the issue
breaking of first h2 text `2 days trial` into 2 lines is causing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top;`

```
.Card {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 30rem;
    margin: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
    padding: 0rem;
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
      vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One more best solution is you can tile your cards into full width which I have shown in demo. (for responsive mode)

**Responsive CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { 

/*** You can change the responsive screen size as per your requirement.

    .Card {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;  
     }
 }
```

**Full Demo:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.header {
  background-color: #1b9ef2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20rem;
}

.header h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 15rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.CardContainer {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -6rem;
}

.Card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30rem;
  margin: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
  padding: 0rem;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

.Card h2 {
  color: #1b9ef2;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding:2.5rem;
}

.cardimgcontainer
{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

.Card img
{
  width:80%;
  height:40%;
  max-height:180px;
  text-align:center;
}

.Card .Price
{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  padding:2.5rem;
  line-height:1.5rem;
  color:rgb(70,70,70);
}

.Card .Price .bold
{
  font-weight:800;
  font-size:1.4rem;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { 
 .Card {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Choose your subscription plan
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="CardContainer">
  <div class="Card">
    <h2>2 Days Trial
    </h2>
    <div class="cardimgcontainer">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/0d/e6/b3/0de6b34699563781365b286c45359692.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="Price">
      <span class="bold">$9.99
      </span>
      <br />1 account
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Card">
    <h2>Personal
    </h2>
    <div class="cardimgcontainer">
      <img src="http://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/090/876/original/rolling-hills-landscape-vector.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="Price">
      <span class="bold">$29.99
      </span>
      <br />5 accounts
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Card">
    <h2>Advanced
    </h2>
    <div class="cardimgcontainer">
      <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/968424/screenshots/2287311/2015_10_12_flatlandscape_800x600_v01_1x.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="Price">
      <span class="bold">$39.99
      </span>
      <br />10 accounts
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Card">
    <h2>Business
    </h2>
    <div class="cardimgcontainer">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/18/fe/3f/18fe3f54a4ae949f7993442a9d8a3447.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="Price">
      <span class="bold">$49.99
      </span>
      <br />50 accounts
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add     `vertical-align: top;` for the Card class.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout is looking good in big screen That's why you need to write this code only for small devices so You can try the below code.

---

```
@media (max-width: 768px){ 
  .CardContainer .Card{
    float: left;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `vertical-align:top;` to `.Card`.

Because you have used `display:inline-block` So, by default it is `vertical-align:baseline;`

> And it will align the baseline of the element with the baseline of the parent element.

[Your updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOWArg)

```
.Card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30rem;
  margin: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
  padding: 0rem;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the job:

```
.CardContainer .card {vertical-align:top;}
```